# plupload, preserve_headers = false, and autorotation issue

Tags: exif, plupload, autorotate, exiftool

I have a jpeg image where the EXIF Orientation flag = 6, or "Rotate 90 CW".  Here's the pertinent data from exiftool:

```
---- ExifTool ----
ExifTool Version Number         : 12.44
---- File ----
File Name                       : orig.jpg
Image Width                     : 4032
Image Height                    : 3024
---- EXIF ----
Orientation                     : Rotate 90 CW
Exif Image Width                : 4032
Exif Image Height               : 3024
---- Composite ----
Image Size                      : 4032x3024
```

Here's how IrfanView presents the image, with auto-rotate turned off:

[image: the image top is to the left, indicating a 90 CW rotation is needed]

Using the plupload "Getting Started" script from [here](https://www.plupload.com/docs/v2/Getting-Started), with preserve_headers = false, I get an image without EXIF headers - as expected - but rotated 180 degrees, which is unexpected.  Again, the view with IrfanView:

[image: the top of the image is now to the right - a 180 degree rotation]

Here's the "resize" snippet from the code:

```
resize: {
            width: 5000,
            height: 5000,
            preserve_headers: false
        }
```

Is there something I'm doing wrong?  I would have expected a 90 CW rotation on upload with the EXIF stripped.

Dan

*Edit:  I'm using plupload V2.3.9*

**BUMP**

I'm getting the exact same result with plupload using [these exif samples](https://github.com/ianare/exif-samples/tree/master/jpg/orientation) on github.  I chose landscape_6, because it's Orientation is the same as my example ("Rotate 90 CW", or Orientation tag value 6).  Here's the before and after upload views using IrfanView with no autorotate, preserve_headers = false:

[image: before plupload]

[image: after plupload]

Aren't these canonical examples for demonstrating exif properties?  Unless I'm missing some fundamental point, plupload is busted.  I'd much rather it be the former, and someone can tell me the error of my ways.

Comment: Try running this exiftool command on the file to see if there is more than one `Orientation` tag, which sometimes happens with bad software.  `exiftool -G1 -a -s -Orientation file.jpg`

Comment: Nope - just the one:   

exiftool -G1 -a -s -Orientation orig_90CW.jpg  


[IFD0]          Orientation                     : Rotate 90 CW

Comment: Just an FYI - the image I've been testing with was produced with an iPhone.  I have an image produced with a Samsung, again with Orientation 90CW.  Same result.  Does anyone have an idea about how I can further diagnose?

Comment: @StarGeek, in the Samsung image I referenced, there are indeed two Orientation tags - IFD0 and IFD1.  This reference, however, says that IFD1 pertains to the thumbnail:  https://www.media.mit.edu/pia/Research/deepview/exif.html

Comment: It was a long shot that multiple `Orientation` tags were the problem.  I've seen it before, but rarely.  Sorry I can't be more helpful.